# nifi 1.8.0 contains log4j-core 2.8.2 and log4j-core-1.x, how to custom build nifi 1.8.0 to use latest log4j

Tags: log4j, pom.xml, apache-nifi

I'm using an older version of Nifi 1.8.0. At this moment upgrading nifi is NOT an option.
security scan identified vulnerabilities in old log4j-core-2.8.2.jar, log4j-core-2.9.1 (remote execution vulnerabilities) and log4j-1.x.jar (no longer supported) in various nar files under
the /nifi/work/nar/extensions/<nar_file_name>/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/

opt/nifi/work/nar/
extensions/nifi-elasticsearch-client-service-nar-1.8.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/
log4j-core-2.9.1.jar

Installed version 2.9.1
Fixed version 2.12.2 <==== for which I'd really want to upgrade to 2.17.0

I checked the nifi 1.8.0 pom.xml file, it has a dependency on

```
 </dependency>
            <!-- logback-classic, logback-core, log4j-over-slf4j, jul-to-slf4j,jcl-over-slf4j,slf4j-api handling this explicitly  Must be in root lib -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

in which <org.slf4j.version>1.7.25</org.slf4j.version>

I tried to change this version to 2.0.7 which is said to be safe.
However after build ,under the nar bundle, I still see log4j-core-2.8.2.jar.

Is there a way to upgrade the log4j version?

Answer (score 0):

simply specify dependency of log4j-core and log4j-api version dependency explicitly in pom.xml works.

Or
https://github.com/apache/nifi/commit/4bcd03024a419afdf40d464bda716f0b9d21925b